# How to set blubuntu theme?

Tags: themes

I just installed all [blubuntu-theme](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/blubuntu-theme/) packages from **Synaptic**. I thought I would now find a new entry in the list I find on *System Settings > Appearence > Look > Theme*, but I still find only Ambience, Radiance and High Contrast as always. How do I use the theme I just installed?

Comment: Perhaps a restart will bring it up, did you restart?

Comment: @George of course I did! That's rule nr1 of all computers :) it didn't work

Comment: Try my answer below it should as this is how I do mine!

Answer (score 0):

once you installed successfully, open Appearance Preferences from the System->Preferences->Appearance menu and select the Blubuntu appearance

you could also install from command-line as below.

```
sudo apt-get install blubuntu-look
```

Comment: I can't find a "System" entry from my Dash. There is only System Settings, System Monitor and System Log. Moreover I already installed all `bluebuntu-theme` dependencies, `blubuntu-look` included!

Comment: Hi, what is your Ubuntu distribution?